# Mobile website without subdomain

Tags: mobile, version, subdomain

I have a website which checks the user agent and loads a mobile version if needed. It loads www.mydomain.com/mobile.

But, like this website "stackoverflow", there isn't a subdomain: it's just "stackoverflow.com" for the desktop and mobile version. How is this done?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

www is not a subdomain, it's a host name.  And what happens here is just DNS in action.
Let's look up [www.stackoverflow.com](http://www.stackoverflow.com)

```
www.stackoverflow.com. 3600 IN CNAME stackoverflow.com
```

This says: "`www.stackoverflow.com` is an alias for `stackoverflow.com`, look up `stackoverflow.com` to know the IP address", so now we look up stackoverflow.com

```
stackoverflow.com. 3600 IN A 64.34.119.12
```

And there it is, the IP address.  That's part 1 of the story.

Regarding the technique SO uses to serve mobile and desktop versions using the same URL, because the StackExchange software that powers SO isn't open source I can only quote Jeff Atwood, from [a comment on a blog post regarding the mobile version](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/07/mobile-stack-exchange/#comment-60071)

> unfortunately, that approach doesn’t work at all for sites like us
> that are actually serving up different HTML to mobile clients.

which leads me to the speculate that the desired rendering (mobile or desktop) is part of your session, and the page controller just applies another set of templates to the article contents, that are stored in a database.

Comment: @FelixBernhard my pleasure, but did it answer your question?

Comment: Yes! But I think I won't change my code.. I just have a folder called "m" and it is used if the user agend is a mobile device: m.mydomain.com